# Can grep show only result i want

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, cygwin

I have data as this

```
tatusx2.atc?beginnum=0;8pctgRB Mwdf fgEio"text1"text4"text
tatqsx3.atc?beginnum=1;8pctgRBwsaNezxio"text2
tatssx4.atc?beginnum=2;8pctgsvMALNejkio"data2
tatksx4.atc?beginnum=1;8pctgxdfALNebfio"text3
tatzsx5.atc?beginnum=3;8pwerRBMALNetior"datac
```

How to get only data between ; and "
I have tried `grep -oP ';.*?"' file` and got output :

```
;8pctgRBMwdffgEio"
;8pctgRBwsaNezxio"
;8pctgsvMALNejkio"
;8pctgxdfALNebfio"
;8pwerRBMALNetior"
```

But my desired output is:

```
8pctgRB Mwdf fgEio
8pctgRBwsaNezxio
8pctgsvMALNejkio
8pctgxdfALNebfio
8pwerRBMALNetior
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use lookahead and lookbehind regex expressions

`grep -oP '(?<=;)\w*(?=")'`

I consider you play around [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to learn more about regular expressions.  Checkout their cheatsheet.

Comment: Hi @azmath ,it got a problem here , if data is `tatusx2.atc?beginnum=0;8pctgRBMwdffgEio"text1"text9"text10"textn` ,it will return output `8pctgRBMwdffgEio"text1"text9"text10"`

Comment: Hi azmath ,how about have some blanks in data ?

Answer (score 1):

A much more readable way to write the expression you need is:

```
grep -oP '(?<=;).*(?=")' file
```

and will get you the desired result. PERL regexes are apparently experimental but certain patterns work without issues.

The following options are being used:

```
-o --only-matching to the print only the matched parts of a matching line
-P --perl-regexp
```

Using `?=;` will get you the string beginning with **;** but using the `>` you are able to start at the index after. Similarly the end string tag is specified.

Here is suggested [additional reading](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm).

Comment: `PERL regexes are apparently experimental` that's been in the manual for so long now.. it would certainly help if they can add at least some cases where it doesn't work.. I've not encountered any so far..

Comment: also, this could be simplified to `grep -oP ';\K[^"]+(?=")'` or even `grep -oP ';\K[^"]+'` depending on usecase